# What is a soul? Does it exist in all living things?

Tags: atma, jiva, human

What is a soul? Does it exist in all living things? If yes, then what is difference between;

1. Souls of two human beings
2. Souls of a human being and another living thing

Comment: The second part of your question is a duplicate of this question - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attached-to-the-body/6787#6787 - Please edit your question so it is only the first part.

Comment: Visit [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6689/277) post.