# The difference between Atman and Brahman

Tags: atma, brahman

Like the Brahman, the Atma also has several similar qualities like opminpresence, omnipotence, divinity etc. Then what is the difference between Brahman and individual Atma?

Comment: Good quest. This answer may be of help, atleast partially, for the various different answers that you would get based on the various sects. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/4056/119. :)

Comment: duplicate of http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6689/3500

Comment: One of the four mahavakyas of the four vedas, this one from the Atharva-veda, is 'ayam atma brahma'  - this soul, this individual Self, this atman, is Brahman. You can find it in the Mandukya Upanishad 1.2 and also Brhadaranyaka Upanishad II.5. It indicates the unity of the individual atman with the Supreme.

Comment: @AnilKumar you meant is Brahman and Paramatma are same?

Comment: @Pandya i didn't mean it. Same question was asked before. So i closed it as duplicate.

Comment: @AnilKumar then how they are *same*? explain. because I didn't find Brahman at [that](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6689/3500) question.

Answer (score 2):

Brahmam (Paramatma) and the individual soul (Jivatma) differ as follows:oug
1.Brahmam is Vibhu (All pervading) and Jiva is Anu (Atomic). 
2.Brahmam is Unique and there is no second like Him- neither above nor Equal to Him. Jiva are countless but are identical in Svaroopa (Defining characteristics)
3.Brahmam is naturally self sustaining and infinite in every aspect of Gyana (Knowledge), Bala (Strength), Aishwarya (Wealth), Veerya (Potency), Shakthi (Power) and Tejas (Opulence) with which He is the cause for Creation, sustenance and annihilation of the Universe. Jiva is enabled by Brahmam to have all the same attributes but is not empowered in the activities of creation,sustainance and annihilation.
4. Brahmam can liberate the bonded Jiva from the Karmic cycle which Jiva is incapable of.

Comment: You should cite sources for your answers.

Comment: It will be useful if contrasted with the commonality in Atman and Brahman.