# What is the relation/difference between Brahman(ब्रह्म) & Parabrahm(परब्रह्म)?

Tags: atma, brahman

Actually first thing to know is: The relation/difference between Atman & Brahman but [that](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9141/277) question is closed as the duplicate of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6689/277). I don't know the exact reason may be Brahman of [a](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9141/277) question might be considered as Paramatma of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6689/277).

So, I am not talking about the difference between Atma,Jeevatma or Paramatma.

My question is **What is the relation/difference between Brahman (ब्रह्म) and ParaBrahm (परब्रह्म)?**

By the way, the different terms used are as follows:

- Jeeva(जीव) or Jeevatma(जीवात्मा)
- Atma(आत्मा) & Paramatma(परमात्मा)
- Brahman(ब्रह्म) & Parabrahm(परब्रह्म)

*If we can define and determine the relation or difference (i.e. which are same, which have relation with another or what is the difference) of above terms, then it will be good for everyone who is confused from this.* [Indeed to answer]

Or currently what is called Parabrahm(परब्रह्म) and how is it related to Brahman(ब्रह्म)?. (If the word "Para(पर)" means beyond, then what do you men by *beyond brahman*? ; And which is (not Brahman?) the Absolute and Ultimate Truth?

Comment: I guess (I could be totally wrong about this) parabrahman is probably a devotional term that was invented to create a difference between Brahman (the abstract entity) and Ishvara (the personal entity). According to devotees, the Personal entity Ishvara is Superior to the abstract entity Brahman, and therefore He may be called as Parabrahman. However in normal conversations, I think they both refer to same being (Abstract or Personal). All the best.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Brahman can be thought of in its as Saguna Brahman and as Nirguna Brahman. Parabrahman refers to Nirguna Brahman.

Ramakrishna Paramahamsa says (*Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna*, Chapter 10, *The Master and the Brahmo Devotees (III)*):

> MASTER: "When the Godhead is thought of as creating, preserving, and destroying, It is known as the Personal God, Saguna Brahman, or the Primal Energy, Adyasakti. Again, when It is thought of as beyond the three gunas, then it is called the Attributeless Reality, Nirguna Brahman, beyond speech and thought; this is the Supreme Brahman, Parabrahman."

This is discussed also in Brhadaranyaka Upanishad II. iii. 1-6 and is sometimes referred to as Para Brahman and the Apara Brahman. These being the only two ways that humans can think or comprehend Brahman in their minds.

Answer (score 3):

I will give an answer according to the school of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.

The all pervading, personal Brahman described by the Upanisads is only the effulgence of the light coming out of God's (Sri Krsna's) divine body. It is from this Brahmanjyoti that we Jivas manifest from. Parabrahman refers to the source of the Brahman, or Bhagavan Sri Krsna who is completely Sat-Cid-Anandmayi. This truth is summarized by Srila Krsnadas Kaviraj Goswami as follows:

> yad advaitaṁ brahmopaniṣadi tad apy asya tanu-bhā ya ātmāntar-yāmī
>   puruṣa iti so ’syāṁśa-vibhavaḥ ṣaḍ-aiśvaryaiḥ pūrṇo ya iha bhagavān sa
>   svayam ayaṁ na caitanyāt krṣṇāj jagati para-tattvaṁ param iha
>
> Translation:  What the Upaniṣads describe as the impersonal Brahman is
>   but the effulgence of His body, and the Lord known as the Supersoul is
>   but His localized plenary portion. Lord Caitanya is the Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa Himself, full with six opulences. He is
>   the Absolute Truth, and no other truth is greater than or equal to
>   Him.

Comment: does vedas differentiate between parabrahman and brahman ?

Comment: when sugna brahman is there what will happen to nirguna form of god do they co -exists The state god changes as nature changes which is against veda which is god is same every where, anywhere and whenever .. he is one who is not changing.. other wise he becaome kshara as jeevas

Comment: @PrasannaR Nirguna Brahman never undergoes parinama, but vivarta. So there's no question of brahman becoming kshara.