# What is the difference between Brahman,ParaBrahman,Bhagvan,Ishvara and ParamAtma?

Tags: gods, brahman, atma, vedic-gods

What are the differences between the various terms. I assume Ishvara might be Sagun Rupa of Brahman but so is Isvara? Are they all same?

Comment: Bhagavata Purana defines these brahman bhagavan paramatma all different. Ishwara is the yeah, you're true, the Saguna roopa of Parabrahman. But do not get confused in names. Eternal reality is One. I call it water, and someone calls it H2O, someone calls in Jala and some one calls in Paani.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti so are Bhagvan and Isvara one and the same? What about Brahman and ParamAtma?

Comment: Srimad Bhagavatam describes Brahman as eternal light of Shri Krishna, and Paramatma is antaryami rupa by which he pervades in all life forms. While appearance is different, Krishna when he pervades in all life forms, he's the Paramatma and in his own nature without anything is Parabrahma swaroopa.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti so Brahman = BrahmJyoti  ParmAtma = Supersoul present in each one of us.ParaBrahman = Nirgun aspect of God Ishwara = Saguna aspect of God Who is Bhagvan then?

Comment: Nirgun is one school says. As per bhagavata Purana, Bhagavan is Parabrahman. krishna is bhagavan.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9617/277

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti so Bhagvan is parabrahman.and Ishvara is another name of Bhagvan while Brahman is BrahmJyoti.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā might be.The main question is are isvara and bhagvan same? Should I ask another question for this?

Comment: all word are same once you accept advaita then they have this suguna and nirgunama brahman.. then confusion starts