# What is Parbrahman? Is it any different from Nirgun Brahman?

Tags: advaita, brahman

I've heard words like brahman, nirgun brahman, sagun brahman, parbrahman etc. Though I've got a fair idea of what nirgun and sagun brahman is, I still am not acquainted with Parbrahman.
Does it refer to nirgun brahman? Or is it a completely different concept?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relation/difference between Brahman(ब्रह्म) & Parabrahm(परब्रह्म)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/what-is-the-relation-difference-between-brahman%e0%a4%ac%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%ae-parabrahm%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%ac%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%ae)