# What are the different types of Shariras (bodies) and their Tatvas?

Tags: vedas

I've heard in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et1X0Bf-EwA) about the 5 types of Sharira (body). I remember Sthul sharir, Sukshma sharir, Kaaran sharir, Anand sharir. And Sukshma, Kaaran, Anand sharir each have 17 tatva. What are these sharir and their tatva? What are their significance?

Comment: Very Excellent Question You asked.

Comment: There are only 3 kind of bodies- Sthula, Sukshma and KArana or parA..  where did u hear about the other 2 kinds?

Comment: @Rickross I got it from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et1X0Bf-EwA Please let me know your comments on this.

Comment: @user5155835 Nothing to comment as there are only 3 kinds of bodies and not 5..may be he using some further sub categories which are not that known..

Comment: anyways i have added the video link in the Q..@user5155835

Comment: Related: [What are three Sharira and their relation to five Kosha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14712/277) and [What are Five Layers (Pancha Kosha) of Human?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3073/277)

Answer (score 3):

According to Sarira Traya, the Doctrine of the Three bodies in Hinduism, the human being is composed of three sariras or "bodies" They are often equated with the five koshas (sheaths), which cover the atman. The Three Bodies Doctrine is an essential doctrine in Indian philosophy and religion, especially Yoga, Advaita Vedanta and Tantra.

The [**Taittiriya Upanishad**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79792.html)  Anuvaka two- Brahmavalli  - Chapter 10-15 is describing these five Kosha's ,  Aman is covered by these 3 bodies or 5 kosha's.

---

## Sthula Sahrira  or  the Gross body   i.e.  the Annamaya Kosha (food sheath)

The Sthula Sharira or Gross Body and the Tatvas Or Elements  associated with it are described in [**Sariraka Upanishad**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/tmu/tmu17.htm)  of KṚSHṆA-YAJURVEḌA.

Out of 24 elements, the physical  body of us  consists of five gross elements i.e  Panch-Maha bhutas. They are - Pruthvi, Jal, Tej, Vayu, and Akash.

> The body is a compound of pṛṭhivī (earth) and other mahābhūṭas
>   (primordial elements, as pas or water, agni or fire, vāyu or air, and
>   ākāś). (In the body), that which is hard is (of the essence of) earth;
>   that which is liquid is (of the essence of) water; that which is hot
>   is (of the essence of) fire; that which moves about is (of the essence
>   of) vāyu; that which is perforated is (of the essence of) ākāś. **The
>   ear and others are the jñānenḍriyas (organs of sense). The ear is of
>   the essence of ākāś, the skin of the essence of vāyu, the eye of the
>   essence of fire, the tongue of the essence of water, and the nose of
>   the essence of earth; sound, touch, form, taste, and odour being
>   respectively the objects of perception for these organs.** These arose
>   respectively out of the primordial elements, beginning with earth. The
>   mouth, the hands, the legs, the organs of excretion and the organs of
>   generation are the karmenḍriyas (or organs of action). Their functions
>   are respectively talking, lifting, walking, excretion, and enjoyment.
>   Anṭaḥkaraṇa (or the internal organ) is of four kinds—manas, buḍḍhi,
>   ahaṅkāra, and chiṭṭa. Their functions are respectively
>   saṅkalpa-vikalpa, (or will-thought and doubt), determination, egoism,
>   and memory. The seat of manas is the end of the throat, that of buḍḍhi
>   the face, that of ahaṅkāra the heart, and that of chiṭṭa the navel.
>   The bone, skin, nādis, nerves, hair, and flesh are of the essence of
>   earth. Urine,

---

## Suksma Sharira or  the Subtle body. This Sukshma Sharira is made up of three koshas

This Sukshma Sharira is made up of three koshas

Sukshma sharia consists of the 19 elements  out of total 24 . Sometimes Ahamkar and Chitta are not included as part of sukshma sharira  namely, five Prāns, Vishays, or Tanmatras; ten Indriyas, four Antahkarans, namely, Man, Buddhi, Chitt, and Ahamkar.

Adi Shankaracharya in his work [**Atma Bodha**](http://www.swamij.com/shankara-atma-bodha.htm)  is describing this Subtle body and the Tatvas associeated with it.

> पञ्चप्राण-मनो-बुद्धि-दशेंद्रिय समन्वितम | 
>  अपंचीकृतभूतोत्थम
>   **सूक्ष्मांगम** भोगसाधनं || 13||
>
> Panch-prān-mano-buddhihi dashendriya-samanvitam 
>   a-panchikrut-bhutotham **sukshma-angam** bhog-sādhanam.
>
> The five Pranas, the ten organs and the Manas and the Buddhi, formed
>   from the rudimentary elements (Tanmatras) before their “five-fold
>   division and mutual combination with one another” (Pancheekarana)
>   **and this is the subtle body**, the instruments-of-experience (of the individual)

---

Pancha pranas are the 5 major vital energies . - Prana , Apana ,Samana, Udana ,Vyana .

---

Five Jnanendriya - Five Sense Organs & their   five Tanmatras  and their elements.

- Ghrana - Gandha - smell. Associeated with  earth.
- Rasana - Rasa - taste.  Associeated with water element.
- Chakshu - Rupa  -  visual sight .  Associeated with fire element.
- Tvak - Sparsha -  touch . Associeated with air element.
- Shrotra - Shabda -  hearing .Associeated with Akasha element.

  ---

  Antaḥkaraṇa  energy -:
- manas -  lower mind
- buddhi -  intellect
- Chitta - subconscious mind
- ahaṃkāra -ego

  ---

  ## Karana sharira  or the Causal body, the Anandamaya Kosha (Bliss).

karana Sharira is  causal body which is cause for the gross and subtle bodies .i.e Karana sarira is the cause of Sthula sharira and Sukshma sharira. 
**The Casual body consist of [35 elements](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XA9zEw93KXEC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=karana%20sharira%20in%20hinduism%20scripture&source=bl&ots=WBeLj2T6ad&sig=0lZb69JmcXGbHpq8Li2gWSFlXFA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil7LzDtsnZAhWMVLwKHTB5CxQQ6AEIhQEwBw#v=onepage&q=karana%20sharira%20in%20hinduism%20scripture&f=false)  or tatvas** -  16 elements of Sthula Body - 19 elements of subtle body. The presence of casual body is indicated in Deep-Sleep or Turiya state.