# What is the Jiva Atma? What is the Paramatma? Are they Different? Is the Jiva-Atma the Mind, Or Are They Different?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, vedanta, atma, jiva

Basically, the title are my questions. I have heard the jiva atma and the paramatma used interchangeably, but then they are separated in, for instance, Vaishnavism. Is it the case that when we are in the state of Daitwa Vedanta these two concepts are different entities, but when we are in the state of Adwaita Vedanta these two concepts become one?

Comment: This question is already answered here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6689/what-is-difference-between-aatma-jeevatma-and-paramatma?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Vivikta THanks